Why does flann.knnMatch() give empty pair?
I am trying to use flann.knnMatch() from opencv to find feature matches, but sometimes there are some empty pair(closest and second closest neighbors) in the return list. Does anyone know what might be the reason behind this?
Thank you!!
Here is my snippet:
    # Define Parameters for Flann Matching
    FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
    index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
                        table_number = 6,
                        key_size = 12,
                        multi_probe_level = 1)

    search_params = dict(checks = 50)

    # Create a Flann Based Matcher
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

    # Matching from 1 to 2
    matches_1_2 = flann.knnMatch(descriptors1, descrptors2, k = 2)
    
    # Matching from 1 to 2
    matches_2_1 = flann.knnMatch(descrptors2, descriptors1, k = 2)

The matches_1_2 will sometime contain a match pair that is empty, for example:
matches_2_1[456] = ()

a [mre] would help your case. that must include data. the less data, the better.
